# A-frame animation-mixer. How do I transition smoothly between json model animation clips?

Tags: json, animation, model, three.js, aframe

I've just recently got started on using A-Frame and I have a question about the animation-mixer.

I'm working on a webVR project and I need to animate a rigged json model. 
So far I have the model loaded and animating on the idle state:

```
<a-entity    
            id ="myModel"
            scale="1 1 1"
            position="1 0 -2"
            rotation="0 0 0"
            animation-mixer="clip: idle"   
            json-model="src: url(/models/json/myModel.json);">

</a-entity>
```

I can change the animation state to something like running by setting the attribute:

```
document.querySelector('#myModel').setAttribute("animation-mixer","clip: run");
```

But doing it that way causes an abrupt change in the animation.
Is there a way to blend the animations so that it transitions smoother?

I've tried looking into Three.js, and it seems like it's possible, but I'm just not sure how to go about it using A-frame. 
Any code snippets or links to an example would be a tremendous help.

Thanks!

Comment: Good question! At this point `animation-mixer` doesn't support crossfading, but as you point out three.js does. So it would be necessary to patch the component, or make a custom component based on it.

Answer (score 3):

Good ol' Don McCurdy updated his animation-mixer component so that this is now possible. Check it out. Includes a link to a working example.

https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders

: )